# sql join multiple tables on same values

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I have 3 tables that use a category code and an identification code to determine one unique value, lets call it a record. There are values with the same identification code and different category codes so I need to join both values for each of the 3 tables.

I am very new to SQL so I am probably making a simple mistake, but my third table's results are not lining up with the rest of the results on the returned lines.

My best guess is that is b/c I have multiple results for table a but only 1 result for table c, but that is also the case for table b and the table b data is accurate.

Sampple Code

```
select a.category_code,
   a.identification_code,
   a.multiple_values,
   b.date,
   c.unique_value        

from table_1 a 
join table_2 b
on a.category_code = b.category_code
and a.identification_code = b.identification_code
join table_3 c 
on c.category_code = a.category_code
and c.identification_code = a.identification_code
Where a.multiple_values in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
and trunc(b.date) >= '01-MAY-2013'
and trunc(b.date) <= '31-MAY-2013'
```

Sample results

```
category_code/ identification_code/ multiple_values /   date      / unique_value
1520        /     557892211       /        a        / 05/25/2013  /    Iowa
1520        /     557892211       /        b        / 05/25/2013  /    Utah
1520        /     557892211       /        c        / 05/25/2013  /    Arizona
1520        /     557892211       /        d        / 05/25/2013  /    Texas
1520        /     557892211       /        e        / 05/25/2013  /    Arkansas
1520        /     557892211       /        f        / 05/25/2013  /    Kansas
```

The problem I have is in the actual data the unique value for 1520-557892211 is Iowa, but I am only getting the correct value once and for the rest of my data the unique values are not mapped correctly.

Comment: . . What is your question?  Can you provide sample data and expected results?  Also, it is good form to tag the question with the database you are using (I'm guessing Postgres or Oracle).

Comment: What DBMS? What are the data types of the columns? What is "trunc(b.date)" returning, and how does "trunc(b.date)" match up to a string value? Please [edit] to post your database schema, some sample data, and the output you'd expect from that data; while you're at it, you can add the appropriate tag for the DBMS you're using. Thanks.

Comment: Updated post as requested. thank you.

Comment: Results look right to me, if only because you haven't provided the data in the table.  Use http://www.sqlfiddle.com to create a schema with test data and the query you are running so we can see what is going on and how to fix it.